# How to built scatter plot in Tableau with only 2 measures?

Tags: tableau-api, scatter-plot, tableau-desktop

I am trying to built scatter plot in Tableau using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv

I want all points to be plotted but Tableau is aggregating(summing) and plotting 1 point. How can I do this? I am able to get required scatter plot in seaborn/python but want to do it in Tableau
[image]

Comment: Note that Tableau is plotting the *sum* of the measures, hence you get only one point. you might need to generate a unique row number and then drag that to the "Detail" shelf to plot a point for each row.

Comment: @Pritesh Or you can turn off Aggregation from the Analysis menu

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlexBlakemore for the suggestion in the comments: Turning off aggregation in analysis and changing it to attribute worked instantly!